# Do international students in the US without income need to file tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident

I am an international student holding an F-1 visa since August 2009, and I did not have any income last year (2015). I got a part-time job early December 2015 but the first paycheck came January 6 this year. I also started a C-corp in December 2013 but I have never received paychecks or any income from it. Do I have to file income tax? In previous years, I did not file tax when I did not have any income, and I saw [this webpage](https://iss.washington.edu/no-income#toc0) says I might have to file Form 8843, but the information is from 2015. I want to know a firm answer about this.Thank you.

---

**EDIT**: I live, go to school and work in the state of New York.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't file Form 8843, as you are not an exempt individual anymore. You are not an exempt individual as a student if you have been an exempt individual as a student for any part of 5 previous calendar years, which you have in 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, and 2013. So in 2014 and later, you are not an exempt individual as a student.

If you didn't get paid in 2015, you shouldn't have to file a tax return. Not sure about the corporation.

Comment: I am just asking about my personal income tax. So I just do not need to file anything for myself personally?

Comment: @DylanChen: You said that you didn't get any income in 2015, so you wouldn't have to file. You could still file if you want (though in your case it would most likely be all zeroes).